# How to get started with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have never done anything with XSLT and I need to write an XSLT script or some other script to add a header and a trailer to XML files that we are FTPing to a location.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do not be discouraged by the downvotes or possible closing of your question.  [Questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are supposed to be more specific than yours.  [**I'll try to get you started**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35439112/290085), but if you could edit your question and add more specifics such as sample XML input, desired XML output, and current XSLT code you've tried, you'll overcome the objections to your question in its current form and you'll help us help you in a way consistent with the norms of this site.  Thanks.

Comment: header that needs to be added -> O*N05TG03897       ,CLS=CRAA16OP,XXX,BAT=,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TransmissionData>
<DocumentID>2016-02-16T10:51:16.0368721880</DocumentID>
<CreatedDateTime>2016-02-16T11:05:28.25</CreatedDateTime>
<Source>
<COD>
<RoutingID>00000001</RoutingID>
</COD>
</Source>
<Destination>
<School>
<RoutingID>123456789</RoutingID>
</School>

Answer (score 5):

### XSLT Quick Start

1. Create a sample input XML file:

   ```
   <root>
     <header>This header text</header>
     <body>This is body text.</body>
   </root>
   ```
2. Run the identity transform,

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. And be sure that you generate the same XML as the input XML:

   ```
   <root>
     <header>This header text</header>
     <body>This is body text.</body>
   </root>
   ```
4. Then add another template to treat the `body` differently

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <!-- New template for body element -->
     <xsl:template match="body">
       <!-- Copy body as-is like in the default identity template -->
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
       <!-- Do something new here: Add a footer element -->
       <footer>This is new footer text</footer>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
5. And run the new XSLT to generate new XML output containing a footer
   this time:

   ```
   <root>
     <header>This header text</header>
     <body>This is body text.</body>
     <footer>This is new footer text</footer>
   </root>
   ```
6. Continue in this manner until your output is fully as desired.

**Recommended XSLT Resources**

- [**XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference**](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0470192747.html) by Michael Kay
- [**XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations**](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1) by Dimitre Novatchev
- [**XSLT Tutorials**](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/) by Jeni Tennison

Comment: Is it possible to have certain headers dependent on the file name? Like if a file name is "RedFile.xml" include RedFile somewhere in the header?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, `base-uri()` will give the filename of the current input XML document; in XSLT 1.0, you have to pass the filename in as a parameter.

Comment: How do you run the transform? Can you use a command line to run it or what?

Comment: The file starts like this:<b>

Comment: Maria, this site is not designed to support a series of questions in comments.  Please first research your problem on your own, and if you're still stuck, ask a new question following the guidelines found in **[ask]**.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry. I found out on Friday that we can create a simple batch file to add headers. Someone in my office told me I had to use XLST so that is why I was researching here and asking questions. We should probably be able to accomplish what we need to via Batch file.