# XML transformation automation

Tags: xml, xsd, automation

I have a desktop application which takes an XML file as an input. I have to create new XML file when new functionality gets introduced to the application.

The format of the new XML is 80% similar to existing one. Hence automation of this XML will reduced my time by 80% for new enhancement.

I already thought about XSD, but I don't know if this is the right way or not.

Or is anything else possible for XML transformation automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT is ideal for transforming XML automatically**, provided you're up for learning a declarative programming language.

When the new XML is 80% similar to the existing XML, start with the identity transformation,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which will copy over XML identically.

Then add templates to cover how the new XML should differ from the old.  For example, adding this template to the identity transformation,

```
<xsl:template match="not-needed"/>
```

will prevent `not-needed` elements from being transformed into the new XML.

And this template,

```
<xsl:template match="old-element">
  <new-element/>
</xsl:template>
```

will replace `old-element` (and everything beneath it) with `new-element`.

Or, this template,

```
  <xsl:template match="old-element">
    <new-element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new-element>
  </xsl:template>
```

will replace `old-element` (but *not* everything beneath it) with `new-element`.

It's common to be able to create identity-based transformations in this manner in minutes.  Fortunately, this sort of power extends to more complicated transformations as well with a similarly high results-to-effort ratio.

See also: [**How to get started with XSLT?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35438518/290085)