# How to get parents sibling value until a condition is reached using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am fairly new to XSLT and this my xml

```
<q>
  <w>
    <p>
      <b>b1</b>
    </p>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <p>p3</p>
    <p>
      <b>b2</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>b3</b>
    </p>
    <p>p4</p>
    <p>p5</p>
    <p>
      <b>b4</b>
    </p>
    <p>p6</p>
  </w>
</q>
```

I need my output to look something like this

```
<position_1_b1>
  <p>p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
</position_1_b1>
<position_2_b3>
  <p>p4</p>
  <p>p5</p>
</position_2_b3>
<position_3_b4>
  <p>p6</p>
</position_3_b4>
```

There is no b2 related tag in output because next 'P' element has an element 'B' in it!

```
<p><b>b2</b></p>
<p><b>b3</b></p>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you say whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0, or are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: The title suggests a procedural algorithm. The language is declarative, not procedural.

Comment: yes 2.0 is okay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grouping in XSLT2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[b][following-sibling::*[1][self::p][not(b)]]">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('position_', position(), '_', normalize-space(.))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except self::p[b]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(b)]">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[b]"/>
```

Comment: thank u for quick turn around! it would be great if u can suggest be best sources for xpath and xsl as i am totally new to it.

Comment: you can learn on https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/ or w3schools, also stackoverflow is always able to help you on any issue

Comment: @vinaypeta: See, for example, [***How to get started with XSLT?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438518/how-to-get-started-with-xslt)