# Change few tags only using XSLT transform

Tags: xslt

I have a large json message and, I want to change some fields values only. Rest of fields should be sent exactly same as input message. Without hardcoding each item in xslt, is there a way to change selected items only?

XML input payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <glossary>
      <title>example glossary</title>
      <GlossDiv>
         <GlossList>
            <GlossEntry>
               <Abbrev>ISO 8879:1986</Abbrev>
               <Acronym>SGML</Acronym>
               <GlossDef>
                  <GlossSeeAlso>
                     <element>GML</element>
                     <element>XML</element>
                  </GlossSeeAlso>
                  <para>A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.</para>
               </GlossDef>
               <GlossSee>markup</GlossSee>
               <GlossTerm>Standard Generalized Markup Language</GlossTerm>
               <ID>SGML</ID>
               <SortAs>SGML</SortAs>
            </GlossEntry>
         </GlossList>
         <title>S</title>
      </GlossDiv>
   </glossary>
</root>
```

Sample Payload

```
{
    "glossary": {
        **"title": "example glossary",**
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    "glossary": {
        **"title": "New value",**
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have bold the changing fields

Comment: "json message" and XSLT? Is that XSLT 3? Or how is your JSON represented as input to XSLT (which in XSLT 1 and 2 usually deals with XML input)?

Comment: I'm using XSLT1. I can convert the message to xml. If so, is there any possibility to change some tags only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get started with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438518/how-to-get-started-with-xslt)

Comment: Please post a sample of the input you have for your XSLT together with the wanted output and explain how items/field to be changed should be indicated if you don't want to hardcode them. How is the XSLT supposed to implement changes for exactly which elements or attributes?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - I updated the question with a sample message and expected output message.

Comment: @KittyKotte Please post the **XML** input.

Comment: Updated the question with XML input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of XML to XML that is basic XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="glossary/title">
      <xsl:copy>New Value</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using the identity transformation template plus additional templates for the elements or attributes (or nodes in general) you want to transform.

Transforming to JSON is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.